# SQL Comparing 2 values that must be determined

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to Find out the course with the most passes from my table tblResults.

```
tblResults:
StuID       Course         Symbol
1001        CSC101         P
1001        RNG101         F
1002        CSC101         P
1002        RNF101         F
1003        HAP101         P
1004        HAP101         P
```

i.e should give CSC101 (And all other courses (HAP101) with the same ammount of passes)

I have tried:

```
CREATE VIEW Part1 AS
SELECT NumbF
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(Course) AS NumbP,
          Course
   FROM tblResults
   WHERE Symbol = 'P')
GROUP BY Course);


CREATE VIEW Part2 AS
SELECT MAX(NumbP) AS Maxnum
FROM Part1,
     tblResults
WHERE Symbol = 'P'
GROUP BY Course;


SELECT Part1.Course
FROM Part1,
     Part2
WHERE Part1.NumbP = Part2.MaxNum
```

But I seem to be doing something incorrectly. Please help

Comment: There is a paranthesis too many in Part1. In Part2 you access Part1.Symbol which is not existent in that view.

Comment: BTW: You should not use that old join syntax with comma-separated tables. There is a newer syntax that was introduced in 1992 where you explicitely name the joins: INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, CROSS JOIN etc. Use this for readability and for it being less prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
create view yourview as
select course, count(*) passcnt
from tblResults
where symbol = 'P'
group by course

select *
from yourview
where passcnt = (select max(passcnt) from yourview)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d377d4/1)

Note, you don't need the view, I just left it for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT Course, count(StuID) count
    FROM tblResults
    GROUP BY Course
    HAVING count = (SELECT max(c)
                    FROM (SELECT count(StuID) c, Course
                          FROM tblResults
                          GROUP BY Course
                          WHERE Symbol = 'p'
                         ) counts
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SELECT below, but I haven't tested it:

```
SELECT selA.Course, selA.NumPass FROM (
    SELECT Course, COUNT(Course) AS NumPass FROM
        tblResults GROUP BY Course HAVING Symbol = 'P') AS selA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(NumPassCount) AS NumPassMax FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(Course) AS NumPassCount FROM
            tblResults GROUP BY Course HAVING Symbol = 'P') AS selB)
        AS selC ON selA.NumPass = selC.NumPassMax
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of sub queries

```
SELECT Sub3.Course
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(Course) AS MaxCourseCnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Course, COUNT(*) AS CourseCnt
        FROM tblResults
        WHERE Symbol = 'P'
        GROUP BY Course
    ) Sub1
) Sub2
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Course, COUNT(*) AS CourseCnt
    FROM tblResults
    WHERE Symbol = 'P'
    GROUP BY Course
) Sub3
ON Sub2.MaxCourseCnt = Sub3.CourseCnt
```